# How to add a new Class in a Scala Compiler Plugin?

Tags: scala

In a Scala Compiler Plugin, I'm trying to create a new class that implement a pre-existing trait. So far my code looks like this:

```
def trait2Impl(original: ClassDef, newName: String): ClassDef = {
    val impl = original.impl
    // Seems OK to have same self, but does not make sense to me ...
    val self = impl.self
    // TODO: implement methods ...
    val body = impl.body
    // We implement original
    val parents = original :: impl.parents
    val newImpl = treeCopy.Template(impl, parents, self, body)
    val name = newTypeName(newName)
    // We are a syntheic class, not a user-defined trait
    val mods = (original.mods | SYNTHETIC) &~ TRAIT
    val tp = original.tparams
    val result = treeCopy.ClassDef(original, mods, name, tp, newImpl)
    // Same Package?
    val owner = original.symbol.owner
    // New symbol. What's a Position good for?
    val symbol = new TypeSymbol(owner, NoPosition, name)
    result.setSymbol(symbol)
    symbol.setFlag(SYNTHETIC)
    symbol.setFlag(ABSTRACT)
    symbol.resetFlag(INTERFACE)
    symbol.resetFlag(TRAIT)
    owner.info.decls.enter(symbol)
    result
}
```

But it doesn't seem to get added to the package. I suspect that is because actually the package got "traversed" before the trait that causes the generation, and/or because the "override def transform(tree: Tree): Tree" method of the TypingTransformer can only return *one* Tree, for every Tree that it receives, so it cannot actually produce a new Tree, but only modify one.

So, how do you add a new Class to an existing package? Maybe it would work if I transformed the package when "transform(Tree)" gets it, but I that point I don't know the content of the package yet, so I cannot generate the new Class this early (or could I?). Or maybe it's related to the "Position" parameter of the Symbol?

So far I found several examples where Trees are modified, but none where a completely new Class is created in a Compiler Plugin.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am having a similar one, so I was wondering... I think you need to match for the parent of your trait in the transform method, unfortunately. That is, look out for PackageDef and Template, and find all occurrences of your trait in their bodies. Then you can return a transformed PackageDef and Template

Comment: Yes, I got help from a Scala mailing list. But I'm not there yet, as I can only create the class in *the same package*. I will try to post an answer to my own question when I have things sorted out.

Comment: Please answer your question NOW! Because I have the same [question](https://github.com/iron9light/autoguice)

Comment: @iron9light As I said, I have working code to create a class implementing a trait (well, had, I tried lots of stuff and the current state might work, but it did at some point). Unfortunately, I can only create them inside the package of the trait I am trying to implement. After asking fruitlessly for help, both here and in the mailing list, I decided that it was hopeless to try and create a compiler plugin when there is basically no doc, the compiler code is basically comment-free, and the gurus don't have time to help you either. Basically, you either read the compiler code, or you give up.

Comment: I hate 'give up'. I just found [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/), it read info from AST and then generate sources. This 'stupid' way works fine. Anyhow, happy new year!

Comment: Changed my strategy: generate tree after parser, add annotation after typer. And it's works now. [autoguice](https://github.com/iron9light/autoguice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full source code is here: https://gist.github.com/1794246

The trick is to store the newly created `ClassDef`s and use them when creating a new `PackageDef`. Note that you need to deal with both Symbols and trees: a package symbol is just a handle. In order to generate code, you need to generate an AST (just like for a class, where the symbol holds the class name and type, but the code is in the `ClassDef` trees).

As you noted, package definitions are higher up the tree than classes, so you'd need to recurse first (assuming you'll generate the new class from an existing class). Then, once the subtrees are traversed, you can prepare a new PackageDef (every compilation unit has a package definition, which by default is the empty package) with the new classes.

In the example, assuming the source code is

```
class Foo {
  def foo {
    "spring"
  }
}
```

the compiler wraps it into

```
package <empty> {
  class Foo {
    def foo {
      "spring"
    }
  }
}
```

and the plugin transforms it into

```
package <empty> {
  class Foo {
    def foo {
      "spring"
    }
  }
  package mypackage {
    class MyClass extends AnyRef
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven' tried it, but since you're one of the "Gurus", you must have got it right. I would just like to add that, and this has nothing to do with you specifically, I haven't used Scala in months and I can relate to people complaining that the Scala community is unfriendly/unhelpful/exclusive when such basic questions (this is a no-brainer in a Java compiler plugin) only get answered after *months* when *someone puts a bounty on them"*. I asked on the Scala language mailing list and didn't even get useful help there... Please don't take it personally; I am thankful for your answer!

Comment: I understand your view, but please don't judge the Scala community based on this question. Most Scala questions get quality, fast answers, but this one is definitely not a 'no brainer'. It requires someone working on the compiler to know the answer (most people in the Scala team don't read SOV very often), and it's something that `scalac` never does, so it's impossible to find an example. Even though the solution is short, it took me around an hour to get everything running correctly.

Comment: Thanks again! To put it shortly, when someone has a "Java question", they can ask here or on dozen other places, and are sure to find an answer (if there is one), but when a Scala question is neither answered here nor on the Scala mailing lists, then that's it, you're on your own, and that's really depressing. I so wish someone would write a "hardcore Scala" book; "Scala in Depth" is still not finished, and if it's going to be about 200 pages long, it will only scratch the surface of all to "hard stuff". But the hard stuff is a lot harder than Java, and there's not enough potential buyers.