# Create new *package* in a Scala Compiler Plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction, package

In my quest to generate new code in a Scala compiler plugin, I have now created working classes. The next logical step is to put those classes in a new, non-existing package. In Java, a package is basically a directory name, but in Scala a package seems much more complicated. So far I haven't found/recognized an example where a compiler plugin creates a new package.

At my current level of understanding, I would think that I would need to create first a package symbol with:

```
parentPackage.newPackage(...)
// ...
```

and than later create a Tree for the package with PackageDef. But PackageDef doesn't take the symbol as parameter, as one would expect, and searching for:

```
Scala newPackage PackageDef
```

returned nothing useful. So it seems that I don't need to do those two steps together. Possibly one is done for my by the compiler, but I don't know which one. So far, what I have looks like this:

```
val newPkg = parentPackage.newPackage(NoPosition, newTermName(name))
newPkg.moduleClass.setInfo(new PackageClassInfoType(new Scope,
    newPkg.moduleClass))
newPkg.setInfo(newPkg.moduleClass.tpe)
parentPackage.info.decls.enter(newPkg)
// ...
val newPkgTree = PackageDef(Ident(newPkg.name), List(ClassDef(...)))
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck? It looks good so far. You probably want to add the tree to an existing compilation unit, otherwise no code will be generated for your trees.

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember. I also asked on the Scala mailing list, and did not get a concrete answer there either, so I basically gave up on writing the plugin. I just wrote more and more code, and it kept getting uglier, but nothing worked.

Comment: Mailing List link: http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/963923c78201f5e6 What I need is the simplest example where one is in transform() or transformStats(), and from there creates a totally unrelated class in a totally unrelated package. There must be a way of adding trees at the root package level, instead of only inside the current package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my answer to your other question should answer this one as well:

[How to add a new Class in a Scala Compiler Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797769/how-to-add-a-new-class-in-a-scala-compiler-plugin/9236583#9236583)